# Почему происходит ошибка "unclosed character literal" в методе, который возвращает сколько слов в строке s начинаются с заглавной буквы?

Tags: java, строки, char

**Условие задачи:**
Написать статический метод `int countCapitals(String s)`, который возвращает, сколько слов в строке `s` начинаются с заглавной буквы.

Заглавной буквой считается символ (`Character`) типа `UPPERCASE_LETTER` или типа `TITLECASE_LETTER`. Словом считается последовательность букв или цифр, разделённых одним или несколькими пробельными символами (`whitespace`), знаками (`symbol`) или знаками пунктуации (`punctuation`).

**Моё решение:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P33 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(countCapitals(s));
    }
    static int countCapitals(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if ((Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)) || Character.isTitleCase(s.charAt(i))) && (i == 0 || Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i - 1)) || checkSymbol(s.charAt(i - 1)))) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    private static boolean checkSymbol(char c) {
        char[] symbols = {'.', ',', '-', ':', ';', '?', '!'};
        for(int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++){
            if(symbols[i] == c){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ошибки:

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: тип `char` - это один символ, а у вас целых 3: 'тАФ'. Остальной код напишите текстом, так его никто читать не захочет

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, а как это можно решить, чтобы был только 1 символ?

Comment: А, я понял. Вы вместо тире (дефиса) указали какой-то страшный символ `\u201d`

Comment: тАФ — это тире в него так превратилось?

Comment: `\u201d` — разве это не кавычки `”`?

Comment: Наверное. Хотя у меня этот код выводит красивые кавычки. Очевидно, вы копировали откуда-то и что-то лишнее скопировалось

Comment: Да, последнее это тире, вот я заменила "–" на "-" и у меня все заработало.

Comment: «Сам код(на фото)» — уберите ваше фото и добавьте код текстом